# Reduce a matrix to a vector using tidyr in R

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have 10 100x100 matrices stored in a list (raw_data). I would like to convert by row each matrix in a column vector and bind all the columns in a single dataframe.

Basically, for each matrix A

```
A <- matrix(c(1:6), nrow = 2, ncol = 3)

A
[[1, 2, 3],
 [4, 5, 6]]
```

and B

```
B <- matrix(c(7:12), nrow = 2, ncol = 3)

B
[[7, 8, 9],
 [10, 11, 12]]
```

I would like to get a single dataframe:

```
A, B
1, 7
2, 8
3, 9
4, 10
5, 11
6, 12
```

This the solution I am using at the moment,

```
fun <- function(x) data.frame(as.vector(t(x), mode = "numeric"))    # Tidyr
var_data <- lapply(raw_data[variables], fun)    # Tidyr
var_df <- do.call(cbind, var_data)  # Tidyr
names(var_df) <- variables
```

however it is not efficient and I would like to use something like tidyr instead. Is there an alternative option?

EDIT:
The list raw_data is the following:
    raw_data = list(A,B)

Comment: Your matrices don't match your "pictures"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about,

```
as.data.frame(lapply(raw_data, c))
#  X1.6 X7.12
#1    1     7
#2    2     8
#3    3     9
#4    4    10
#5    5    11
#6    6    12
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `matrix`

```
matrix(unlist(raw_data), ncol=2, dimnames= list(NULL, c("A", "B")))
#    A  B
#[1,] 1  7
#[2,] 2  8
#[3,] 3  9
#[4,] 4 10
#[5,] 5 11
#[6,] 6 12
```

Wrap it with `as.data.frame` if we need as a `data.frame`